# (Angular 2/Spring boot) is not routing to previous page

Tags: angular, spring-boot, angular2-routing

I design a simple login page, an admin page using Angular 2 is front end and Spring boot with Spring security as back end. The expected behavior should be following:

`1. User didn't authenticate, and try to visit localhost:4200/admin
2. Admin guard should fired, and route the page to login page with state.url = '/admin'
3. User enter the username, password and once successfully authenticate, it should route to localhost:4200/admin`

But the actual behavior is, once user click login on the form, it hanging and it didn't redirect, but in the header it already change to the username. Once I refresh the page, it already login and route to home page. Why this issue happen and how can I fixed it?

Here is `admin.guard.ts`

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, CanActivate, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot } from '@angular/router';
import { UserService } from '../user/user.service';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

@Injectable()
export class AdminGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(private router: Router, private userService: UserService) {}

    canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean {
      if (this.userService.currentUser && JSON.stringify(this.userService.currentUser.authorities).search("ROLE_ADMIN") !== -1) {
        return true;
      } else {
        console.log("NOT AN ADMIN ROLE");
        this.router.navigate(['/login'], { queryParams: { returnUrl: state.url }});
        return false;
      }
    }
  }
```

Here is the `login.component.ts`

```
import { Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { DisplayMessage } from '../shared/models/display-message';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs/Subscription';
import { AuthService } from '../shared/';
import { UserService } from '../user/user.service';
import { Observable, Subject } from 'rxjs';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/interval';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.scss']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
  title = 'Login';
  githubLink = 'https://github.com/zhengye1/Eatr';

  form: FormGroup;

  /**
   * Boolean used in telling the UI
   * that the form has been submitted
   * and waiting for response
   */
  submitted = false;

  /**
   * Used for displayed error message 
   * from received form request or router
   */
  notification: DisplayMessage;

  returnUrl: string;

  private ngUnsubscribe: Subject<void> = new Subject<void>();

  constructor(private userService: UserService,
    private authService: AuthService,
    private router: Router,
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.route.params
      .takeUntil(this.ngUnsubscribe)
      .subscribe((params: DisplayMessage) => {
        this.notification = params;
      });
      // get return url from route parameters or default to '/'
      this.returnUrl = this.route.snapshot.queryParams['returnUrl'] || '/';

    this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
      username: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.minLength(3), Validators.maxLength(64)])],
      password: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.minLength(3), Validators.maxLength(32)])]
    });
  }
ngOnDestroy() {
    this.ngUnsubscribe.next();
    this.ngUnsubscribe.complete();
  }

  onResetCredentials() {
    this.userService.resetCredentials()
    .takeUntil(this.ngUnsubscribe)
    .subscribe(res => {
      if (res.result === 'success') {
        alert('Password has been reset to 123 for all accounts');
      } else {
        alert('Server error');
      }
    });
  }

  repository() {
    window.location.href = this.githubLink;
  }

  onSubmit() {
    /**
     * Innocent until proven guilty
     */
    this.notification = undefined;
    this.submitted = true;

    this.authService.login(this.form.value)
    // show me the animation
    .delay(1000)
    .subscribe(data => {
      this.router.navigate([this.returnUrl]);
      //this.userService.getMyInfo().subscribe();
    },
    error => {
      this.submitted = false;
      this.notification = { msgType: 'error', msgBody: 'Incorrect username or password.' };
    });

  }
}
```

The `login.component.html`

```
<div class="content" fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="center">

    <md-card elevation="5" fxFlex>

      <md-card-subtitle>
        <h2>Eatr Application</h2>
      </md-card-subtitle>

      <md-card-title>
        <h2>{{title}}</h2>
      </md-card-title>

      <md-card-content>

        <p [class]="notification.msgType" *ngIf="notification">{{notification.msgBody}}</p>

        <form *ngIf="!submitted" [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" #loginForm="ngForm">
          <md-input-container>
            <input mdInput formControlName="username" required placeholder="user/admin">
          </md-input-container>
          <md-input-container>
            <input mdInput formControlName="password" required type="password" placeholder="123">
          </md-input-container>
          <button type="submit" [disabled]="!loginForm.form.valid" md-raised-button color="primary">Login</button>
        </form>
        <br>
        <div *ngIf="!submitted" >
          <button mdTooltip="Reset password if someone has changed it already!" (click)="onResetCredentials()" md-raised-button color="accent">Reset Credentials</button>
        </div>

        <md-spinner *ngIf="submitted" mode="indeterminate"></md-spinner>
        <br>
        <hr>

        <p><i>Created by <a href="https://github.com/zhengye1/">Vincent Zheng</a></i></p>
        <p><i>Click below to go to repository</i></p>
        <button (click)="repository()" md-raised-button color="accent">GitHub Repository</button>

      </md-card-content>

    </md-card>

</div>
```

EDIT: Here is the for app-routing

```
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { RestaurantComponent } from './restaurant/restaurant.component';
import { RestaurantDetailComponent } from './restaurant/restaurant-detail/restaurant-detail.component';
import { AdminComponent } from './admin/admin.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';
import { GuestGuard } from './guard/guest.guard';
import { AdminGuard } from './guard/admin.guard';
const routes: Routes = [
   { path:'', component: HomeComponent},
   { path: 'restaurant/:id', component: RestaurantDetailComponent },
   { path: 'restaurant',  component: RestaurantComponent },
   { path: 'admin', component: AdminComponent, canActivate:[AdminGuard]},
   { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent, canActivate: [GuestGuard]}
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [ RouterModule.forRoot(routes) ],
  exports: [ RouterModule ]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

For the full code it is in:https://github.com/zhengye1/Eatr/tree/dev

For the code reference: https://github.com/bfwg/angular-spring-starter, http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2016/09/29/angular-2-user-registration-and-login-example-tutorial#login-component-ts

**EDIT2**

Edit code based on Aravind's comment, the issue still exists. But when I using console to check my logic, I realize following behaviour:
1. Navigate to `/admin` page, trigger the `admin.guard.ts`, and in that time `currentUser` is undefined, and the page route to login page with following url = `/login?returnUrl=%2Fadmin`

2. After I loggin as `admin`, it trigger the `admin.guard.ts`, but at that time `currentUser` still defined, is it the reason that it failed?

Comment: Do you have `/admin` route configured correctly?

Comment: @FanJin I edited the original question

Answer (score 0):

Add a public variable to `UserService` to set the last activated route as below,

```
export class UserService {
   recentRoute: string;

    setRecentRoute(route:string){
        this.recentRoute = recentRoute;
    }
}
```

In your `AdminGuard` set the call the method to set the variable.

```
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean {
        this.userService.setRecentRoute(state.url);
        /// other logics
}
```

In your login component after authentication success,

```
this.authService.login(this.form.value)
    .subscribe(data => {
        /// take the route from the userService
        this.router.navigate([this.userService.recentRoute]);
    },
    error => {
      this.submitted = false;
      this.notification = { msgType: 'error', msgBody: 'Incorrect username or password.' };
    });
```

Comment: Tried, still the same.. is it something wrong on my admin guard logic?